# How to find timber in a truck using MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, image-processing, machine-learning

My problem is to find and count timber in the truck automatically using image with the back of the trailer. Im trying to solve this problem using MATLAB Image Toolbox. So, here is my code.

```
function [ centers, rads, metrics ] = TimberFind( img )
    minrad = 20;
    maxrad = 110;
    Hsens = .93;
    CannySens = .20;

    img_gray = rgb2gray(img);
    PSF = fspecial('gaussian', 5, 0.5);
    img_gray = imfilter(img_gray, PSF, 'symmetric', 'conv');
    img_gray = imadjust(img_gray);
    PSF=fspecial('gaussian', 10, 1);
    Blurred = imfilter(img_gray, PSF, 'symmetric', 'conv');
    cont = imsubtract(img_gray, Blurred);
    preprocessed = imadd(img_gray, 3*cont);    

    bin = edge(preprocessed, 'canny', CannySens);

    [cen, r, m] = imfindcircles(bin, [minrad maxrad],'Sensitivity', Hsens);  
end
```

But the result is not very good. You can see [the full data](https://cloud.mail.ru/public/2c6Dgdw2yFi6/stackoverflow) set or the following example: 
[image: first input image]
[image: first output image]

So, if I make Canny and imfindcircles algorithms sensetive enough to detect all timber, there are some excess resoults found. I have an idea to solve this problem with cutting out each timber from the big image, then constucting some global criteria of obtained small pictures, and try some machine learning algorithm on it. But I think this way is rather difficult, so maybe somebody could suggest anything else? Maybe there is a better way to make preprocessing of the image before using Canny operator? If you have any idea how to make it better, please tell me. Thanks!

Comment: Can you post the original images, _i.e._ without the red circles ?

Comment: Sure, I put them into the cloud.

Comment: If you see your false detections, some of them are easy to remove using post-processing. For example, the appearance of false detections is different from the other circles you find.

Comment: Yes, I actually did it. I also tried to remove false resoults using brightness and texture parameters, but pictures are to different (day/night, summer/winter), so I can't managed to solve problem correctly by removing false detections using some threshold. And I thought about machine learning.

Answer (score 4):

Actually there is not really a need to preprocess your images, *i.e.* neither going grayscale, Gaussian filtering nor Cany edge detection are actually useful before using [`imfindcircles`](http://fr.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imfindcircles.html).

A simplified version of your code gives a very decent result on this image:

[image]

The code:

```
minrad = 20;
maxrad = 110;
Hsens = .93;

[cen, r] = imfindcircles(img, [minrad maxrad],'Sensitivity', Hsens);
```

And the result:

[image]

Interestingly, the result is much better that what your original code does. The simpler the better !

Comment: Using your way leads to bad resoult on my images. But I really made a mistake when used edge detection, because imfindcircles does it by itself. So, I fixed it and the resoult become better, but not good enough.